# where to specify URL when implementing IHierarchyData

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I've implemented IHierarchicalDataSource, IHierarchicalEnumerable and IHierarchyData. The TreeView displays everything correctly. But where should I specify the URL that should redirect the user where needed when he clicks on the TreeView's item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented SiteMapProvider instead of IHierarchicalDataSource and it worked fine.